# Laravel - Return array index from file

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I am using laravel 5. I have a file structure like the below:

```
+App
    +Http
        +Controllers
            +ExampleController.php
    +Lang
        +Files
            +Items.php
```

In my ItemsFile.php, I return an array like so:

```
<?php

return array(
'item1' => 'Toys',
'item2' => 'Shoes',
'item3' => 'Clothes',
'item4' => 'Cars',
);
```

I want to return an index from the ItemFile.php in my ExampleController.php file like this:

```
$selected = Lang::get('Items.item1');
```

But I get errors such as: Class 'App\Lang' not found

What do I need to do to include this functionality? I think it has something to do with namespaces but I am not sure what.

Comment: Add "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;" to your controller

Comment: @BaikHo Thank you, that corrected the error but instead of printing out the value, it just outputs the string that I passed in. For example:

'Items.item1' is output instead of 'Toys' from the above example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use [Localisation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization) I see a couple of weird things:

1. In laravel 5 the language files should be in `resources`. Like `resources/lang/en/item.php`.
2. You seem to be missing a language folder. Like `/en/` in my example above.
3. You don't have to import a class to translate something, you could just use: `trans('item.item1');`

So if you set it up like this it should work:

> /resources/lang/en/items.php

```
return array(
    'item1' => 'Toys',
    'item2' => 'Shoes',
    'item3' => 'Clothes',
    'item4' => 'Cars',
);
```

> /app/http/Controllers/ExampleController.php

```
$selected = trans('items.item1');
dd($selected);
```

#### note:

The language folder used is the `locale` specified in `config/app.php`.

Comment: I think this is what I am missing, thank you! @bjorn